# Is it possible to avoid copying a temporary class instance passed to a function that saves a pointer to it?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++17, object-lifetime

I have a class `Holder` with a vector that holds instances of different classes (e.g. `Derived`) derived from the same abstract base class (`Base`). I constructed it as a vector of pointers to the base class to support polymorphism. New instances are added to the vector  via a method called `add`. The new classes are constructed inside the parentheses when calling `add` and are not named (this mechanism is supplied to me and cannot be changed).

I do not quite understand what the lifetime of this constructed class is and how can I prevent it from being destructed right after exiting `add`. It has to be constructed, so is there a way to keep it alive and hold a valid pointer to it? Or will I have to create a copy and let the passed temporary die?

I am using C++17, none of my classes allocate memory manually, only STL containers and primitive data types are used. I've been looking at `std::move()` but I did not find what I needed. Example code:

```
class Base
{
public:
  std::vector<int> vec;
  virtual void foo() = 0;
}
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived(int a, int b)
  {
    vec.push_back(a);
    vec.push_back(b);
  }
  void foo() override;
}
class Holder
{
public:
  std::vector<Base*> ptrs;
  void add(Base& arg)     // What should be the type of arg? (Does not have to be Base&)
  {
    ptrs.push_back(&arg); // How should I add a pointer to arg into ptrs so that
                          // arg stays alive after returning from this method?
  }
}
int main()
{ 
  Holder h;
  h.add(Derived(1, 2));   // this is how add() gets called, I cannot change it
  ...
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, I can change the signature and body of `add` as well as the data type that vector `ptrs` uses. I cannot change the way `add` is called (`h.add(Derived(1, 2));`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main`

the parameter passed is a temporary destroyed just after the call to `add` returns. You may store this value, the address, but you must never dereference it.

If you want to ensure the the object remains valid for the lifetime of `Holder` your only option is taking over the ownership of an existing object or making a copy you've got ownership of.

**Taking ownership of an existing object**

For this using `std::unique_ptr` would be preferrable to make the ownership clear.

```
class Holder
{
    ...
    void add(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& arg)
    {
        //preferrably make ptrs a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> and use ptrs.emplace_back(std::move(arg)) or
        ptrs.push_back(args.get());
        args.release(); // make sure the object gets deleted before or during destruction of the Holder object
    }
};
```

**Making a copy**

Use the move constructor here to void a copy

```
class Holder
{
    ...

    template<class T>
    void add(T&& arg)     // What should be the type of arg?
    {
        ptrs.push_back(new T(std::forward<T>(arg));
        // Note: make sure the object created here gets destroyed
    }
};
```

---

**EDIT**

According to the updated answer this is the implementation of `Holder` I'd go with:

```
class Holder
{
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> ptrs; // make this private?

    template<class T>
    void add(T&& arg)
    {
        // better compiler error on incorrect use
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>,
                      "parameter passed must be an object of a class derived from Base");

        ptrs.reserve(ptrs.size() + 1); // if an std::bad_alloc happens, this gives you a strong exception guarantee
        
        ptrs.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<T>(args)));
    }
};
```

Note: This only works with a virtual destructor of `Base`; if this isn't an option, you'll need to save logic for invoking the correct destructor alongside the object. You do not prevent the creation of the temporary `Derived` object, but at least it's possible to use the implicitly created move constructor of `Derived` to prevent unnecessary copies of the elements  of `Base::vec`

Comment: I cannot suggest an edit, so heads up a third `)` is missing on the last line, in case anybody will want to copypaste this. Anyways this was precisely what I needed, thanks.